# Python numpy difference between reshape(v.shape) & reshape(*v.shape)

Tags: python, numpy

I found myself struggled in the following two region of codes(which exactly did the same job),can anyone tell me what the difference?

Code1:

```
v = np.zeros((2,5))
value_one = np.linspace(-1.4, 1.3, num=v.size).reshape(*v.shape)
```

Code2:

```
v = np.zeros((2,5))
value_two = np.linspace(-1.4, 1.3, num=v.size).reshape(v.shape)
```

Comment: As far as I can tell from the docs, `reshape` should be called with a tuple so I'd go with `Code2` ...

Answer (score 2):

Since `reshape` can accept either ints or tuple of ints both version are ok. You can verify by

```
value_one = np.linspace(-1.4, 1.3, num=10).reshape(2,5)

value_one = np.linspace(-1.4, 1.3, num=10).reshape((2,5))
```

The stared version `*v.shape` will strip the tuple to its elements.

Comment: Thank you, that make sense. One more question, I got invalid syntax when I tried to ( print *v.shape), how can I get the stripped results of the tuple?

Comment: I'm on python3. Here `print(*v.shape)` results with `2 5`, while `print(v.shape)` results with `(2, 5)`